# Loop with wrong number of lines in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, append

I've created a script but the loop on the script is not being respected. For some reason it's returning more lines that should (only 3 lines would be the correct return).

The sample.txt file has the follow content:

```
Server1
Server2
Server3
```

In my code, it should do the append using only the 3 servers from the sample.txt, however, the output which I'm getting is:

```
[{'ApplicationName': 'App01', 'ServerList': ['server1'], 'StartDate': '2020-12-12 12:00:00', 'EndDate': '2020-12-12 13:00:00', 'SourceTool': 'Moon'}]
[{'ApplicationName': 'App01', 'ServerList': ['server1'], 'StartDate': '2020-12-12 12:00:00', 'EndDate': '2020-12-12 13:00:00', 'SourceTool': 'Moon'}, {'ApplicationName': 'App01', 'ServerList': ['server2'], 'StartDate': '2020-12-12 12:00:00', 'EndDate': '2020-12-12 13:00:00', 'SourceTool': 'Moon'}]
[{'ApplicationName': 'App01', 'ServerList': ['server1'], 'StartDate': '2020-12-12 12:00:00', 'EndDate': '2020-12-12 13:00:00', 'SourceTool': 'Moon'}, {'ApplicationName': 'App01', 'ServerList': ['server2'], 'StartDate': '2020-12-12 12:00:00', 'EndDate': '2020-12-12 13:00:00', 'SourceTool': 'Moon'}, {'ApplicationName': 'App01', 'ServerList': ['server3'], 'StartDate': '2020-12-12 12:00:00', 'EndDate': '2020-12-12 13:00:00', 'SourceTool': 'Moon'}]
```

Below is the how would be the correct output:

```
[{'ApplicationName': 'App01', 'ServerList': ['server1'], 'StartDate': '2020-12-12 12:00:00', 'EndDate': '2020-12-12 13:00:00', 'SourceTool': 'Moon'}, 
    {'ApplicationName': 'App01', 'ServerList': ['server2'], 'StartDate': '2020-12-12 12:00:00', 'EndDate': '2020-12-12 13:00:00', 'SourceTool': 'Moon'}, 
    {'ApplicationName': 'App01', 'ServerList': ['server3'], 'StartDate': '2020-12-12 12:00:00', 'EndDate': '2020-12-12 13:00:00', 'SourceTool': 'Moon'}]
```

What am I doing wrong? Below is the script that I'm using:

```
list = []

with open('sample.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

for x in lines:
    data = {
        "ApplicationName" : 'App01',
        "ServerList" : [x], 
        "StartDate" : '2020-12-12 12:00:00',
        "EndDate" : '2020-12-12 13:00:00',
        "SourceTool" : 'Moon'
        }
    list.append(data)
    print(list)
```

Comment: This is because your `print(list)` statement is inside the `for` loop. If you align it with the for it should show correctly

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your code. You just need to print the list outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're good. But try printing after the loop is done; unindent print once.

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe it was only this detail... thank you guys, it is working now. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. You simply need to unindent the `print(list)` and it will work. Currently, the `print` statement is inside the `for` loop.

Here is the fixed code:

```
list = []

with open('sample.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

for x in lines:
    data = {
        "ApplicationName" : 'App01',
        "ServerList" : [x], 
        "StartDate" : '2020-12-12 12:00:00',
        "EndDate" : '2020-12-12 13:00:00',
        "SourceTool" : 'Moon'
        }
    list.append(data)

print(list)
```